# AJAX request with POST method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, request

So this is a To-do app that works by writing an item in input field and then storing it an `array` of object and then using `EJS` to show the data.

I used an `AJAX` request(by using `XHR`) to the url and stuff but it seems like it doesn't work at all, actually I did some tests and it seems like the whole submit event function doesn't work but even then, I tried to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` but it gave me an error of some `"an expected token 0 at position 0"`

What's wrong? I use `Express.js` for server rendering, `EJS` as a view engine, and Javascript for sending requests.

Setting up the server stuff(a seperate module, App will be later a module of `express`):

```
let items = [];
let bodyparser = require("body-parser");
let urlencoded = bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get("/todo", function(req, res) {
    res.render("toDo", { data: items });
  });
  app.post("/todo", urlencoded, function(req, res) {
    items.push(req.body);
  });
  app.delete("/todo:item", function(req, res) {});
};
```

HTML file(By using EJS):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>To-do Application</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../Public/Assets/Styles.css" />
  <script src="../Public/Scripts/Add.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="todo-table">
    <form action="/todo" method="post">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Write an item here" required>
      <button type="submit" id="Add" onsubmit="return false">Add</button>
    </form>
    <ul>
      <% data.forEach(function(element){ %>
        <li> <%= element.item %> </li>
      <% }) %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file to send AJAX requests:

```
let form = document.querySelector("form");
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/todo");
let valueToAdd = document.querySelector("input").value;
let readyValue = { item: valueToAdd };
form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      request.send(readyValue);
      console.log("Yaay succeeded");
    }
  };
});
```

Whenever I run it, it just doesn't work at all, it doesn't add the item object to the array, the page keeps loading and loading when I press submit button and nothing shows in Network section of Dev tools. It seems like it doesn't work at all. Heck, even `console.log` of `"Yaay succeeded"` doesn't show up which means it has something to do with that function but I just can't figure it out.

Also when I do `console.log(req.body)` it shows an empty object which again means the problem is in that function, it seems like it doesn't send the data or something. Any help?

Comment: inside the submit handler, you need to prevent the default form action - you also need to create the XHR inside there, not outside of it (you would potentially be trying to re-use the XHR object)

Comment: @JaromandaX I did that and also created XHR inside but now the page doesn't reload but nothing gets sent/return either. Now when I click on the button, nothing happens at all.

Comment: Anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the form from actually submitting the form:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
```

further info here -https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: I did that. It still doesn't work. Now whenever I click on the button, nothing gets sent or get received.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this html line:

```
<button type="submit" id="Add" onsubmit="return false">Add</button>
```

Change the onsubmit with onclick:

```
<button type="submit" id="Add" onclick="return false">Add</button>
```

> [From MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit): The submit event is fired when a form is submitted.
>
> Note that submit is fired only on the form element, not the button or submit input. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)

Another solution can be: change type="submit" with type="button"

Comment: I did that. It still doesn't work. Now whenever I click on the button, nothing gets sent or get received.

Comment: This is the second issue: Your ajax call is incomplete.

Comment: then how I fix it and complete it?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't completing the request when you send a POST to '/todo'; The server has nothing to tell the client that the request has completed, thus the webpage keeps spinning forever.

Send an HTTP status code of OK or No Response (204) when the action is completed like this

```
app.post("/todo", urlencoded, function(req, res) {
  items.push(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: I did that. It still doesn't work. Now whenever I click on the button, nothing gets sent or get received. I believe that the problem is in JS XHR function, I think it doesn't send any data whatsoever, it's the reason why req.body is empty.

Comment: @Boypro Try adding the "request.send(readyValue);" before the "request.onreadystatechange" event listener. Right now you are getting a response and then trying to send data to the server.

Comment: Now the situation gets improved a little, before I apply your last solution, whenever I do console.log(request) in the if condition, the state always equal 0 which means no request whatsoever, now when I moved request.send before the if condition(like you said), it now shows much more details of the objects like status = 200(Ok) and state = 4, even the url is well. It still doesn't work properly but I think it's one step forward. Any more ideas please?

Comment: Check the newest answer I posted. We can work off of that @Boypro

Answer (score 0):

You add an event listener to the form, but inside that you do not submit the form, but add another event listener to the request's `onreadystatechange` event. Then try a `send()` inside that. Since the request's state won't change just b itself, our `send()` method will never run. I think what you wanted to do is something like this:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      console.log("Yaay succeeded");
    }
  };
  request.send(readyValue);
});
```

This defiens the event handler for the `onreadystatechange` event to handle the response, and after that actually sends the request also, so heopfully when you have the response your event handler will fire, and run the code that handles the response.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Like the other solutions, nothing happens when I click the button now.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for on the frontend.

```
let form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let valueToAdd = document.querySelector("input").value;
  let readyValue = { item: valueToAdd };

  request.open("POST", "/todo");
  request.send(JSON.stringify(readyValue));

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if(request.status === 200) {
      console.log("Yaay succeeded");
    } else {
      console.log(request.status);
    }
  }
 };
});
```

Comment: Nothing changed, sorry ): Like always, when I press the submit button(with onclick = return false) it doesn't send anything at all. When I removed "onclick = return false" it reloads the page with a text of "OK" with it. The new thing in this solution is when I applied it, now it doesn't show any console.log whatsoever ): Any more ideas?

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention something important. When I found "submit" event doesn't work. I changed it click, it still doesn't work fully but before(before I apply our solution) it shows the console.logs and that's why it did that. Because I changed from submit to click. Just thought it might be an important idea.

Comment: I forgot to put the definition of the form variable outside of the actual event listener lol whoops. That should at least make the event listener work

Comment: Yeah I know that. I did it myself when I knew that you forgot to put it outside the event handler. It seems like the problem is so complicated. I guess I either start fresh by using Fetch API or even jQuery or I just wait for some solution I guess.

Comment: I added the code to this fiddle and the request sends as intended. If you console log the req.body in nodejs does it still show as blank?

http://jsfiddle.net/tqkspybL/6/

Comment: All your code doesn't work until I change the event "submit" to "click" when I do that it shows me the value I'm writing and "Yaay succeeded" but the req.body is still empty so it doesn't add anything but blank <li> ): Any last ideas?